# Triggering a GitHub Actions pipeline on commit to a submodule project

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-submodules

I have a project that uses another project as a submodule. The structure looks something like this:

MyProject

-- Dir1

-- Dir2

-- Dir3

-- Another-Project-Link (Another git repo sub-moduled here)

This `Another-Project-Link` is the another git repo which is sub-moduled in the current project. Now what I want to do is whenever there is a push to  `Another-Project-Link` repository, I want to trigger my GitHub Actions pipeline for `MyProject` with the latest changes in `Another-Project-Link`

Is that feasible? Is there another better way to do this rather than using sub-modules?

Comment: The idea behind submodules is that the `parent` repository refers to a specific commit in the submodule and *explicitly* does not see any updates until you manually update the pinned commit in the parent repository. If you wanted to attach a workflow somewhere, you would probably do that in the parent repository, and have it execute when you update the pinned commit.

Comment: If you have a single superproject with this submodule why it's a submodule at all? Why it's not an integrated part of the superproject?